# Problems with Arduino BT

Tags: bluetooth, android

I have an Arduino BT and I can't connect it to any device I have. I've tried in 3 different situations:

Win7 - If I choose 'Connect without a PIN code', the device seems properly detected but it doesn't appears in Device Manager. In the case of the connection with the PIN code, it throws a timeout error.

Win8 - Don't even ask me for the PIN code. A message 'This isn't working. Try again and verify if the device is still visible' appears.

Android 5.0 - When I try to pair and write the PIN code, I get a message 'Invalid PIN or password'.

The PIN is 12345, by Arduino.cc page.

Another different thing is that in the documentation, the board has the Blink code by default. But the orange light on the board doesn't blink, and don't turn green either. I didn't find anything about the color of the LED in this board.

Can anyone help me?